# How to ignore the dynamic fields for indexing but need to store the values?

Tags: elasticsearch

In each document, I have a couple of dynamic fields. I want to ignore these fields for indexing but neet store the complete values in ES. Here I tried with object type and nested type but still, these fields are added for Indexing. Also getting exception lime default number of fields is exceeded.

Example:

```
{
    "graphType": "Node",
    "id": "ETA:bb16f173-8152-4e18-ac15-410438ffaf8e",
    "type": "StateNode",
    "properties": {
        "name": "ETA:ETAViolation",
        "tenantId": "f9688078-9ff9-46b3-9b0d-d1b4d5f875d7",
        "valueHistory": {
            "1597952938315": "1"
        },
        "id": "ETA:bb16f173-8152-4e18-ac15-410438ffaf8e",
        "type": "ETA:ETAViolation",
        "value": {
            "1597952938315": "1"
        },
        "fromId": "bb16f173-8152-4e18-ac15-410438ffaf8e",
        "classType": "StateNode",
        "sid": "ETA",
        "cid": "ETAViolation"
    }
} 


{
    "graphType": "Node",
    "id": "ETA:8541fb08-8c83-4229-804b-92d57e22e9a2",
    "type": "StateNode",
    "properties": {
        "name": "ETA:ETAViolation",
        "tenantId": "f9688078-9ff9-46b3-9b0d-d1b4d5f875d7",
        "valueHistory": {
            "1597952938447": "3"
        },
        "id": "ETA:8541fb08-8c83-4229-804b-92d57e22e9a2",
        "type": "ETA:ETAViolation",
        "value": {
            "1597952938447": "3"
        },
        "fromId": "8541fb08-8c83-4229-804b-92d57e22e9a2",
        "classType": "StateNode",
        "sid": "ETA",
        "cid": "ETAViolation"
    }
}
```

These are two sample documents, In each document two fields **value** and **valueHistory** are there. Inside of these fields, I am getting many dynamic fields like **1597952938315** and **159795293831588**.  I want to ignore these fields for indexing but need to store the fields in ES Index.

Please anyone can help with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, Can you change the document structure? I just want to know can I provide you a solution which requires some changes in our mapping.

Comment: Please change the structure if you want and provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping would be something like this, I omited some repetitive fields.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "graphType": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "tenantId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "nested_value": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "long",
              "store": true
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "integer",
              "store": true
            }
          }
        },
        "from_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "classType": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "sid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and you need to insert data like this:

```
{
  "graphType": "Node",
  "id": "ETA:bb16f173-8152-4e18-ac15-410438ffaf8e",
  "type": "StateNode",
  "name": "ETA:ETAViolation",
  "tenantId": "f9688078-9ff9-46b3-9b0d-d1b4d5f875d7",
  "nested_value": [
    {
      "key": 1597952938315,
      "value": 1
    }
  ],
  "from_id": "bb16f173-8152-4e18-ac15-410438ffaf8e",
  "classType": "StateNode",
  "sid": "ETA",
  "cid": "ETAViolation"
}
```

You can key and values in the nested field. And also you can easily make search on it.